# Do i need to remove all memory management methods in ARC-enabled project?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

my  app is developed with ARC disabled from the beginning, now i decided to take advantage of ARC techniques, when i try to convert the project to ARC i keep getting errors wherever release autorelease methods are exist, does that mean i have to dig into my project and get rid of any methods related to memory management? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are not allowed to use `release`, `retain`, or `autorelease` in ARC code. If it's too much of a hassle, you can disable ARC on a per-file basis as described here: [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

Comment: @mbg1987 There is a refactor option to help converting a project from non-ARC to ARC

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of good references on the web that deal with automatic reference counting, e.g.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1

or

http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html